# asp.net owin token ignoring httpredirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, token, owin, http-redirect

Our API uses OWIN OAuth Bearer Token. It was working properly in an endpoint like https://server1.url/token.

Now we want to redirect the API to a second server (server2). We configured the IIS in server1 to redirect all requests to the API to server2. As far as we noticed, this configurations added an "httpredirect" entry in the web.config.

The problem now is that the token endpoint is not being redirected. All other endpoints are redirected properly to server2, but token endpoint does not redirect, it is processed normally in server1, and we do not understand why.

Does anyone have a guess?

Comment: When `httpRedirect` is enabled, then every request to the Application is handled by IIS, and the IIS simply sends the empty body with the a status like `301` in headers. So then the client is responsible for further requests. But it is really weird, that the IIS doesn't redirect `server1/token` request. What will happen, when you remove the application code, leaving only the web.config with the redirection?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. We will try it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems OWIN pipeline begins before IIS can redirect the request. `httpRedirect` is handled by HttpRedirection Module. And this module is registered by the IIS after OWIN's module, which is register before application start [PreApplicationStart](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs).

So remove the application itself and leave the `web.config` only.

Comment: This change partially fixed the problem.

The request started to be redirected, but we were not getting an acceptable response.
After the change suggestion by @tenbits, we noticed that the POST requests were being requested to the new server as GET. A similar problem was reported here:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

As it suggests, we changed the responde HTTP code to 307. This fixed the second part of the problem.